# How to check whether the Arima() function generate a warning message or not?

Tags: r

I run the following on R

```
library(forecast)
Arima(1:100, order=c(2,0,0))
```

This produces the warning message

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced
```

I want to write a function to check whether the `Arima` output generates an error
message or not?

Comment: See help("tryCatch").

Answer (score 0):

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(1:100, order=c(2,0,0))
warnings(fit)
```

Comment: How about you explain your answer?

Comment: To check whether the fitted model generates a warning or not you can use is.na(warnings(fit))==TRUE